# SONOS API - Is there a way to get player model?

Tags: sonos

I've integrated Sonos API in my Smart Home app, but I didn't find a way to get players model.

Using `/households/{householdId}/groups` endpoint we can get groups and players data, but there isn't a specific field for device model.

How can I get that information?

Answer (score 1):

Call getGroups with includeDeviceInfo=true and its in player.devices[n].modelDisplayName

Comment: I tried and it works! Thanks!
Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: At https://devdocs.sonos.com/reference/groups-getgroups

Comment: Thanks! So they have just updated the docs, old references (like https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/) don't work anymore.

Comment: Right, but no sign of a changelist or revision history so we have to guess what they added and deleted, and when. Not the way to run an API document set.